# Which data structure I should use for store objects in recursive manner in java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to use a data structure which can store 10 objects one by one, if the data structure has overflow then next object should be replaced on first position and other next object should be replaced on second object and so on. I used org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.DescriptiveStatistics class to store double.

```
boolean getValue() {   
  DescriptiveStatistics ds = new DescriptiveStatistics(10);
  while (true) {
    if (ds.getN() == ds.getWindowSize()) {
      double average = ds.getMean();
      if(average>15)
        return true;
    }
    ds.addValue(15.5);
  }
}
```

But now I need this functionality with user defined objects. Is there any api for this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a standard array or an ArrayList.

For the array, you'd want to pre-fill the ten values with some base (Null, for example), and then once all ten are not equal to Null, you know it's full and can just replace whichever should be replaced.

For an ArrayList, once the size of the list is ten, you know it is full and should then start replacing.